# How do I determine, with Powershell, when a specific app was used?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a script in PowerShell, which start the Application and show the user in a Pop-Up when this Application was used the last time. Well, to start the Application I just used a simple command, which is working, but I don't know if it's efficient in a long term:

```
start 'C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\LeagueClient.exe'
```

and after it started the Application and Pop-Up should tell me, when was the last time I started the Application. That's my goal for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could open the program using

```
start 'C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\LeagueClient.exe'
```

and get the pop up like...

```
#First you want to set your variable for the date and time
#Get-ItemProperty is self explanatoy
#select-object gets the LastAccesTime property and -expand isolates that property in a string versus a table
$lastusetime = Get-ItemProperty "C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\LeagueClient.exe" | select-object -expandproperty LastAccessTime

#set the com object for a window and give it a variable
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell

#use that variable and the "Pop Up" property of windows shell to set the Windows details. VOID disables any outputs in the powershell window
[void]$wshell.Popup("Last Open $Lastusetime",0,"Program Details",0x1)
```

To get more information on the Wscript.Shell object you can go to [this link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730993.aspx)

There could be other ways of doing this but this is how i chose to do it.